# Excel - Como concatenar range de células?

Tags: microsoft-excel, fórmula

Como faço para concatenar um range de células no Excel?

Por exemplo: tenho uma coluna com muitas células contendo informação de texto e gostaria de concatená-las, mas ao usar a função concatenar ocorre erro, sendo necessário selecionar uma por uma das células.

A função **`=CONCATENAR(B2:B48)`** desta forma não funciona, sendo necessário reescrever da seguinte forma: **`=CONCATENAR(B2;B3;B4; ... B48)`**.

Em pesquisar encontrei sugestão de usar uma função chamada unirtexto, mas não é reconhecida.

Answer (score 2):

Se você selecionar células em uma coluna, ele não sabe concatenar, mesmo.

Tem que transpor a "coluninha" para funcionar:

Na célula-alvo, comece digitando a função `TRANSPOR()`,

```
=TRANSPOR()
```

Selecione o *range*,

```
=TRANSPOR(B2:B48)
```

Adicione `&" "` no final do *range*,

```
=TRANSPOR(B2:B48&" ")
```

Selecione a função toda; esta parte:

```
TRANSPOR(B2:B48&" ")
```

Aperte a tecla F9 do teclado; ela vai converter o *range* em uma lista. Termine por colocar a função `CONCAT()` em volta da lista,

```
=CONCAT({"O ", "rato ", "roeu ", ...})
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://trumpexcel.com/concatenate-excel-ranges/)

Comment: O Excel 2016 não reconhece, quando copio e colo o resultado só aparece o primeiro registro.

**`=CONCATENAR({"a "\"b "\"c "\"d "\"e "\"f "\"g "})`**

Answer (score 1):

Se você tem o Excel 2016, você pode usar a fórmula `UNIRTEXTO` desta maneira:

```
=UNIRTEXTO(" ",0,B2:B48)
```

aqui a [documentação](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-unirtexto-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c)

Comment: O Excel 2016 em português não reconhece esta função, apresenta um erro de fórmula.

Comment: Na versão em inglês é chamado `TEXTJOIN` na versão em portuges é `UNIRTEXTO`